# Affine transformation matrix.Cant understand the math?

Tags: affinetransform

Cv2.getAffineTransform seems simple but its not...

The getAffine gets in second run perfectly logical result: the matrixindicates a simple translation on x. If we think the mt=A+b;   A=[1,0,0,1] and b=[40,0]

But why is not the same in first run? It is a triangle transformation with +40 in x again...What is the difference???

[[image: In this picture first run gave a weird matrix, but second one the expected translation matrix.Why?]

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the matrix is true: it is actually [1,-1],[0,1],[40,0] but the e-17 e-17 make the number practicallly zero and the e+01 to 40, which was easy. I did not take care of the e thing :)